# My code test does not pass my bubble sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

**Ploblem:**
Bubble sorting is an algorithm that sorts sequences of length N in such a way that two adjacent elements are examined to change their positions. Bubble sorting can be performed N times as shown below.

Compare the first value with the second value and change the position if the first value is greater.
Compares the second value with the third value, and if the second value is greater, it changes its position.
...
Compare the N - 1 and N - values ​​and change the position if the value of N - 1 is greater.
"Supchan" I know the result of bubble sorting, of course. However, since N is very large, it takes a long time to perform the above steps K times. Write a program that will help you to find the intermediate process of bubble sorting.

**My Code**

```
def bubble(list):
    temp = 0
    for i in range(0, len(list)): 
        for j in range(i+1, len(list)): 
            if (list[i] > list[j]):
                temp = list[i]
                list[i] = list[j]
                list[j] = temp
    return list


numbers = input()
items = [int(num) for num in numbers.split()]

print(bubble(items))
```

**Test Condition**

```
N and K are given in the first line.

The second line gives the status of the first sequence. That is, N integers forming the first sequence are given in turn, with spaces between them.

1 ≤ N ≤ 100,000
1 ≤ K ≤ N
Each term in the sequence is an integer from 1 to 1,000,000,000.
```

**Input & Output**

```
input: 3 1 2 5 4
output: 1 2 3 4 5
```

The code I wrote seems to work fine. However, the grading of the coding test rejects me.

I can not understand the reason because the reason is not listed. Is there a problem with my code?

Comment: Are you getting TLE? or something else?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Thanks. What does "Write a program that will help you to find the intermediate process of bubble sorting" mean?

Comment: Perhaps this is an input formatting problem?  The "Test Condition" section says there should be two lines of input, but your program appears to only handle one line?

Comment: _the grading of the coding test rejects me_ Does it give a reason, or just pass/fail?

Comment: @JohnGordon has explained your problem.  Your problem statement is incomplete, but does clearly state that you have two lines of input.  Your program allows only one.  As such, it will almost certainly fail on the first set of real data.  Does the problem statement supply test data?  If so, it appears that you didn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line

```
numbers = input()
```

to

```
numbers = raw_input()
```

It could be that the test input might be in the form

```
1 5 6 4 3
```

instead of

```
'1 5 6 4 3'
```

which might cause error while running using `input()`